# How is product of motions of two planes again a motion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, plane-geometry

I was studying from Vinberg’s “A Course In Algebra” and while discussing operations on algebraic structures, he says :

> For example, according to the axioms of Euclidean geometry, the product of two motions of the plane is again a motion.

Can anyone clarify what he means by product of motions of a plane, and how the end result is again a motion?

Comment: @Henry - good point! The [author](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Course_in_Algebra/kd24d3mwaecC) speaks (page 138) of *isometries* (motions forming a group).

Comment: So IMO the issue is that **using coordinates** to develop plane geometries, we can define "motion" (an undefined concept used originally by Euclid in proving e.g. SAS).

Comment: In the context of isometry groups (and other groups of transformations) *product* means [*the composition* of two transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). First do one, then the other.

Answer (score 0):

A *motion of the plane* will be a translation, rotation, reflection, or glide reflection.

The product of two motions will involve doing one motion and then do the other motion on the result.  The combination will itself be a motion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I have one question : here by translation, rotation etc do you mean translation of the plane or some object on the plane, or both?

Comment: @NiceGuy I am not sure there is a real distinction between the two.  It is a way of explaining what congruent or isometry mean.